# Windows-Ubuntu Dual boot does not show grub screent

Tags: dual-boot

I have a dual boot with Windows and Ubuntu. Earlier I could boot into both Ubuntu and Windows. But I have been using only Ubuntu for last 10 months or so.
Now the grub screen does not show up and it only loads into Ubuntu directly.
If I press Del/F12/F10, it stays stuck on a black screen. If I stop pressing, only then the black screen disappears and Ubuntu loads up.

I have tried to update-grub but that also did not work. How can I log into Windows?

Comment: Please add the output from `sudo update-grub` to your question through [edit]

Comment: legacy BIOS boot or UEFI boot ?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu.

I think that OS-Prober is disabled. This detects all Operating Systems on your system. 
To enable it:

edit /etc/default/grub ( as Root )

add or uncomment ( place a # before the line ) GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

save that file and then run:

`sudo update-grub` or `sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`